# Audio playing too fast

Tags: java, audio, xuggle

If any of my fellow Xuggler users can tell me what I'm doing wrong, that would be awesome! I am doing the following:

1. Reading from ogv (ogg video)
2. Queueing the audio and video
3. Writing back to ogv

sounds simple right? The problem I am experiencing in my QueueMixer class is that the output file plays the audio 2x too fast, and no matter what I check or change with regards to pts it doesnt improve.

The eclipse project and all files being used are at this link: 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7316897/paul-xuggled.zip

To run a test, compile and execute the StreamManager class; a test ogv file is included. Before anyone asks, yes I have to queue the data as it will be mixed with other data in a future version.

Comment: My fellow engineers, don't be put-off by the fact that I'm using ogv (ogg video) here, you can easily change the type of file to flv, mp4, mov, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is to multiply the sample count by two when extracting them from the ShortBuffer.

`samples = new short[(int) audioSamples.getNumSamples() * 2];
audioSamples.getByteBuffer().asShortBuffer().get(samples);`

Having half the samples causes the audio to play twice as fast.

Comment: "2" in this case because I'm using a stereo source

Answer (score 0):

Audio has a sample rate. Make sure that you copy the sample rate from the input to the output, otherwise the system might use a default (like 44KHz while the original data was sampled at 22KHz which would create such an effect).

Comment: There is an adjustment "tool" that is used in the code on the input data to do these conversions. The reason that I don't think its sample rate related is because when using 44100 stereo to 44100 stereo, the issue still occurs.

Comment: What does `mediainfo` say about the output file? Maybe there is a bug.

Comment: I'm not familiar with "mediainfo" but I will take a look at it. I can say that the file seems fine and I have the same result with other files. The problem is most definitely in the queue code, because skipping the queue provides working output at the correct speed.